# How can I reduce lag in the following HTML 5 canvas game?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

I am experimenting with game coding using HTML 5 canvas and JavaScript. My game isn't nearly complete, but I am already experience some prominent lag issues. The game can be found here: http://survival.sthost.net/gunsvsships.html
Also, any other advice on improving functionality would be helpful. Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = $("#canvas").width();
var h = $("#canvas").height();
var cw = 10;

var title = new Image();
var startButton = new Image();
var startButtonSelected1 = new Image();
var startButtonSelected2 = new Image();
var startButtonSelected3 = new Image();
var background = new Image();
var ship = new Image();
var dead_ship = new Image();
var retical = new Image();
var bullet = new Image();
var slug = new Image();
var gunLabel1 = new Image();
var gunLabel2 = new Image();
var gunLabel3 = new Image();
var gunLabel4 = new Image();
var gunLabel5 = new Image();
var gunLabel1Trans = new Image();
var gunLabel2Trans = new Image();
var gunLabel3Trans = new Image();
var currentStartButton = startButton;
var startButtonIncrementor = 0;
var startButtonTimeNow = new Date().getTime();
var startButtonTimeThen = new Date().getTime();
var drawStart = true;
var gun = "Sniper"
var credits = 0;
var dead = 0;
var dead2 = 0;
var dead3 = 0;
var newSpeed = 5;
var bulletSpeed = 8;
var shipX = 0;
var ship2X = 1000;
var ship3X = 0;
var shipY = 250;
var ship2Y = 300;
var ship3Y = 250;
var bulletX = 500;
var bulletY = 550;
var slugAX = 500;
var slugBX = 500;
var slugCX = 500;
var slugAY = 550;
var slugBY = 550;
var slugCY = 550;
var gunType = -1;
var reticalX = 0;
var reticalY = 0;
var reticalX2 = -1;
var reticalY2 = -1;
var drawShipA = true;
var drawShipB = true;
var drawShipC = true;
var drawBullet = false;
var drawSlugs = false;
var now, then = new Date().getTime(), delta;
var sniperSound = new Audio("sniper.wav");
var shotgunSound = new Audio("shotgun.wav");

title.src = "images/title1.png";
startButton.src = "images/start_button.png";
startButtonSelected1.src = "images/start_button_selected1.png";
startButtonSelected2.src = "images/start_button_selected2.png";
startButtonSelected3.src = "images/start_button_selected3.png";
background.src = "images/background.png";
ship.src = "images/ship.png";
dead_ship.src = "images/crashed_ship.png";
retical.src = "images/retical.png";
bullet.src = "images/bullet.png";
slug.src = "images/slug.png";
gunLabel1.src = "images/1.png"; 
gunLabel2.src = "images/2.png"; 
gunLabel3.src = "images/3.png"; 
gunLabel4.src = "images/4.png"; 
gunLabel5.src = "images/5.png"; 
gunLabel1Trans.src = "images/1_trans.png";
gunLabel2Trans.src = "images/2_trans.png";
gunLabel3Trans.src = "images/3_trans.png";

sniperSound.volume = 0.1;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}


$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    reticalX = e.pageX - pos.x;
    reticalY = e.pageY - pos.y;
});

$('#canvas').click(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    reticalX2 = e.pageX - pos.x - 40;
    reticalY2 = e.pageY - pos.y - 40;
    if (gunType == 0){
        if ((Math.abs(reticalX2 - (shipX - 35)) <= 50) && (Math.abs(reticalY2 - (shipY + 35)) <= 50)){
            dead = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(reticalX2 - (ship2X - 10)) <= 50) && (Math.abs(reticalY2 - (ship2Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead2 = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(reticalX2 - (ship3X - 10)) <= 50) && (Math.abs(reticalY2 - (ship3Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead3 = 1;
            credits += 100}}
    else if (gunType == 1 && drawBullet == false){
        drawBullet = true;
        bulletX = reticalX2;
        sniperSound.play();}
    else if (gunType == 2 && drawSlugs == false){
        drawSlugs = true;
        slugAX = reticalX2;
        slugBX = reticalX2;
        slugCX = reticalX2;
        shotgunSound.play();}        
    else if (gunType == -1)
        if ((reticalX >= 370 && reticalY >= 220) && (reticalX < 520 && reticalY < 300)) {
            drawStart = false;
            gunType = 0;}
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (drawStart == false) {
        if (drawBullet == false && drawSlugs == false) {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 49:
                    gunType = 0;
                    gun = "Sniper";
                    break;
                case 50:
                    gunType = 1;
                    gun = "Revolver";
                    break;
                case 51:
                    gunType = 2;
                    gun = "Shotgun";
                    break;}
    }}            

});


function update() {

    if ((reticalX >= 370 && reticalY >= 220) && (reticalX < 520 && reticalY < 280)) {
        if ((startButtonTimeNow - startButtonTimeThen) < 500) {
            currentStartButton = startButtonSelected1;
            startButtonTimeNow = new Date().getTime()}
        else if ((startButtonTimeNow - startButtonTimeThen) < 1000) {
            currentStartButton = startButtonSelected2;
            startButtonTimeNow = new Date().getTime();}
        else if ((startButtonTimeNow - startButtonTimeThen) < 1500) {
            currentStartButton = startButtonSelected3;
            startButtonTimeNow = new Date().getTime();}
        else if ((startButtonTimeNow - startButtonTimeThen) < 2000) {
            startButtonTimeNow, startButtonTimeThen = new Date().getTime(), new Date().getTime();}
        else {startButtonTimeNow, startButtonTimeThen = new Date().getTime(), new Date().getTime();}
    }        

    else {currentStartButton = startButton;}

    if (shipY >= -70 && dead == 0){
        drawShipA = true;
        shipY -= newSpeed;
        shipX += newSpeed;
    }
    else if (dead == 1 && shipY < 600){
        shipY += newSpeed;
        drawShipA = false;
    }            
    else {   
        shipY = getRandomInt(400, 425);
        shipX = getRandomInt(100, 900);
        dead = 0;
        drawShipA = true;
    }

    if (ship2Y >= -70 && dead2 == 0){
        drawShipB = true;
        ship2Y -= newSpeed;
        ship2X -= newSpeed;
    }
    else if (dead2 == 1 && ship2Y < 600){
        ship2Y += newSpeed;
        drawShipB = false;
    }
    else {   
        ship2Y = getRandomInt(400, 425);
        ship2X = getRandomInt(100, 900);
        dead2 = 0;
        drawShipB = true;;
    }

    if (ship3Y >= -70 && dead3 == 0){
        drawShipC = true;
        ship3Y -= newSpeed;
        ship3X -= newSpeed;
    }
    else if (dead3 == 1 && ship3Y < 600){
        ship3Y += newSpeed;
        drawShipC = false;
    }
    else {   
        ship3Y = getRandomInt(400, 425);
        ship3X = getRandomInt(100, 900);
        dead3 = 0;
        drawShipC = true;
    }

    if ((dead + dead2 + dead3 >= 2) && (((Math.abs(shipX - ship2X) + Math.abs(shipY - ship2Y)) + (Math.abs(shipX - ship3X) + Math.abs(shipY - ship3Y)) + (Math.abs(ship3X - ship2X) + Math.abs(ship3Y - ship2Y))) < 1500)) {credits += 50}

    if (drawBullet == true){  
        bulletY -= bulletSpeed;
        if ((Math.abs(bulletX - (shipX + 20)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(bulletY - (shipY + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(bulletX - (ship2X + 20)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(bulletY - (ship2Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead2 = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(bulletX - (ship3X + 20)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(bulletY - (ship3Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead3 = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if (bulletY <= -130){
            drawBullet = false;
            bulletY = 550;
        } }

    if (drawSlugs == true){
        slugAY -= bulletSpeed;
        bulletSpeed = bulletSpeed * 2;
        bulletSpeed = (bulletSpeed - (bulletSpeed % 3))/3
        slugBX -= bulletSpeed;
        slugBY -= bulletSpeed * 2;
        slugCX += bulletSpeed;
        slugCY -= bulletSpeed * 2;
        if ((Math.abs(slugAX - (shipX + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugAY - (shipY + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(slugAX - (ship2X + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugAY - (ship2Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead2 = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(slugAX - (ship3X + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugAY - (ship3Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead3 = 1;
            credits += 100}   
         if ((Math.abs(slugBX - (shipX + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugBY - (shipY + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(slugBX - (ship2X + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugBY - (ship2Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead2 = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(slugBX - (ship3X + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugBY - (ship3Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead3 = 1;
            credits += 100}             
         if ((Math.abs(slugCX - (shipX + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugCY - (shipY + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(slugCX - (ship2X + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugCY - (ship2Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead2 = 1;
            credits += 100}
        if ((Math.abs(slugCX - (ship3X + 10)) <= 40) && (Math.abs(slugCY - (ship3Y + 10)) <= 50)){
            dead3 = 1;
            credits += 100} 
        if (slugAY <= -150){
            drawSlugs = false;
            slugAY = 550;
            slugBY = 550;
            slugCY = 550;}}

}


function paint()
{
    now = new Date().getTime();
    delta = now - then;

    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);

    if (drawShipA == true){ctx.drawImage(ship, shipX, shipY, 70, 70);}
    else {ctx.drawImage(dead_ship, shipX, shipY, 70, 70);}

    if (drawShipB == true){ctx.drawImage(ship, ship2X, ship2Y, 70, 70);}
    else {ctx.drawImage(dead_ship, ship2X, ship2Y, 70, 70);}        

    if (drawShipC == true){ctx.drawImage(ship, ship3X, ship3Y, 70, 70);}
    else {ctx.drawImage(dead_ship, ship3X, ship3Y, 70, 70);}            

    if (drawBullet == true){
        ctx.drawImage(bullet, bulletX + 30, bulletY, 10,10);}

    if (drawSlugs == true){
        ctx.drawImage(slug, slugAX + 20, slugAY, 30, 30);
        ctx.drawImage(slug, slugBX + 20, slugBY, 30, 30);
        ctx.drawImage(slug, slugCX + 20, slugCY, 30, 30);        
    }

    bulletSpeed = calcSpeed(delta, 6);
    newSpeed = calcSpeed(delta, 3);    
    then = now;
    ctx.drawImage(retical, reticalX - 40, reticalY - 40, 80, 80);
    ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 165, 0, 1)"
    ctx.strokeText("$" + credits, 15, 30);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 165, 0, .8)"
    ctx.strokeText(gun, 450, 500);
    ctx.drawImage(gunLabel1, 445, 510, 35, 35);
    ctx.drawImage(gunLabel2, 470, 510, 35, 35);
    ctx.drawImage(gunLabel3, 495, 510, 35, 35);
    switch(gunType) {
        case 0:
            ctx.drawImage(gunLabel1Trans, 445, 510, 35, 35);
            break;
        case 1:
            ctx.drawImage(gunLabel2Trans, 470, 510, 35, 35);
            break;
        case 2:
            ctx.drawImage(gunLabel3Trans, 495, 510, 35, 35);
            break;
            }
    if (drawStart == true) {
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        ctx.drawImage(title, 270, 90, 400, 100);
        ctx.drawImage(currentStartButton, 370, 220, 150, 60);
        ctx.drawImage(retical, reticalX - 40, reticalY - 40, 80, 80);}  
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,w,background.height);
    }

var init = function()

{
    requestAnimationFrame(init);
    update();
    paint();
}   

var calcSpeed = function(del, speed) {
    return (speed * 60 * del) / 1000;
}

init();})
```

Comment: One thing that just flew into my eye: You are using a lot of `if (drawBullet == true)`. You can simply do `if (drawBullet)`.

Comment: What profiling have you done?

Comment: @RononDex that has nothing to do with performance. Regarding lag issues, where do you notice them? On KeyDown? When you click? On redraws? Where exactly do you perceive the slow down?

Comment: You use the function `findPos()` on every mousemove and click, passing the canvas as the parameter. Why not just store that value at the beginning, reducing the calls to that function to just once?

Comment: *It laaaaags!* is what players scream. As a developer you should be able to describe performance problems in more specific terms.

Comment: Jon, how will the interpreter knwo where to draw the retical without calling that function everytime the mouse moves? Could you expound on this?

Chris, the lag I'm noticing is present while using the 'shotgun' or 'revolver' weapons, espec after clicking. I plan to make weapons with more complex animations than those so I am worried it will just get worse.

Comment: Up where you have a bunch of other variables, you can put something like `var canvasPos = findPos(document.getElementById('canvas'));`. Then in your mousemove and click functions, you can do `var pos = canvasPos;`, or simply just use `canvasPos` instead of `pos`.

Comment: @philipp, yea sry about that. To be more specific, the lag I'm noticing has to do with the ships perceived movement, like the framerate is dropping when using the 'shotgun' or 'revolver'. I only notice this in the ships, which I find strange because I tried to sepearte the logic from the drawing as much as possible.

Comment: @user3232117 So you mean the game slows down when there is too much action?

Comment: Exactly. Do you think using a framework will help with this? Or is this just one of the limitations of game development with html 5 canvas? Sorry if I sound like a novice, I haven't really written anything in a few years, and btw, thanks Ronon for reminding me about booleans, now my next post might not look quite so silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your game speed is tied to your framerate:

```
var init = function()

{
    requestAnimationFrame(init);
    update();
    paint();
}
```

When the number of frames per second goes down, so does the number of updates per second. As a result the game slows down when the framerate goes down and speeds up when the framerate goes up. To solve this problem, execute the update-loop in fixed intervals:

```
 window.setInterval(update, 10);
```

That way the game logic will always be updated 100 times per second, no matter how quick or slowly the rendering works right now.

When you do this, you might notice an issue though: You have no control when the drawing happens. It is possible that a call to `paint` happens *during* a call to `update`. As a result it will draw a game-state which is half logic-frame n and half logic-frame n+1. This could cause some weird graphic glitches. I usually structure my game loops like this (psuedocode):

```
 calculated_time_in_ms = getCurrentTimeInMs();

 while(game_is_running) {
     paint();
     while(calculated_time_in_ms < getCurrentTimeInMs()) {
          update();
          calculated_time_in_ms += 10;
     }
 }
```

This way maintaining the game logic framerate always has priority over rendering, but when the graphic engine is fast enough, it is able to draw more often than the game logics update.

Comment: Ok, that actually makes a lot of sense, you explained really well.

Comment: I am kind of new to game development, but for everything that I have read, `requestAnimationFrame` is the way to go. The key is how you use it. Have a read at this [article](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/) to have a better idea.

Comment: It runs silky smooth on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s0urLuc1d/K7hTh/embedded/result/

I can't understand why it would run better on jsfiddle, any ideas?

Comment: Edit: nvm, it's the sound that's causing the issues, jsfiddle version I forgot to link the sounds. So now at least I know where the lag's coming from.

Comment: It is actually not going to help if your hardware is the issue. He should calculate a delta time and update his game objects based on the time elapsed and multiply it. Please add this to your answer.